# Google Analytics API - Export Data to JSON in a form that can be put into S3/Redshift

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am running a Google Analytics API script that I would like to use to export session data.

Right now I am just printing the data:

```
def get_segment_sessions(service, profile_id, segment_id):

    return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      segment='gaid::' + segment_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='yesterday',
      metrics='ga:sessions',
      dimensions='ga:date').execute()

def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
  #  print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
  #  print 'Date: %s' % results.get('date') + ' Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

      output = []
      for header in results.get('columnHeaders'):
        output.append('%30s' % header.get('name'))
      print(''.join(output))

      if results.get('rows', []):
        for row in results.get('rows'):
          output = []
          for cell in row:
            output.append('%30s' % cell)
          print(''.join(output))
```

which looks something like:

```
ga:date                   ga:sessions
                      20170414                          2235
                      20170415                          2203
                      20170416                          2257
                      20170417                          2159
                      20170418                          1921
                      20170419                          2095
                      20170420                           764
```

How do I export this in JSON to be used in S3/Redshift?